# Percent-encoding in url WebRequest 404 error RESTful service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am trying to do WEB simple restful service. My code based on  this article:
http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/A-simple-REST-service-in-C.aspx
I changed it a little bit,so my service can get several parameters.
Here are my changes:

```
 public string GetClientNameById(string LS, string Owner, string info)
{
 .....
 return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(XMLFileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
}
[ServiceContract(Name = "RESTServices")]
    public interface IRESTServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = Routing.GetEPDRoute, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string GetClientNameById(string Id,string LS,string tmp);
    }
public static class Routing
    {
        public const string GetEPDRoute = "/EPD/{id}+{LS}+{tmp}";
    }
```

It works fine with english simbols, but I need use cyrillic simbols.
if I use cyrillic simbols in url, it returns 404 error.
I tried use Percent-encoding but result is the same
Here is my client code:

```
string url = "http://localhost:4385/Service.svc/EPD/995118466+" + System.Uri.EscapeDataString("Аксенова") + "+434";
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE:** I found a solution- just replaced non english simbols by numeric codes,but i would like to find  more elegant solution

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<globalization
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8"
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      resourceProviderFactoryType=""
      enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true"/>
```

add thease parameters in web.config globalization tag

then use something like this

```
//UTF-8
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameter, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
//UTF-16
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameter, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
//UTF-32
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameter, System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but i have no idea where can i put decode operation. it fails before call of  My method. My WCF code file is empty. svc file contains only this <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RESTService.Lib.RESTServices" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"%>

Comment: any idea where i can put HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameter, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)?

Comment: when you get the passed parameter , url